# Class Objective Equality in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I created a class listed below,

```
class Card:
    suitList = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    rankList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=0):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.cards = []
```

Then I add several items to the list of cards.

```
card1 = Card(1, 1)
card2 = Card(2, 2)
card3 = Card(3, 1)
cards.append(card1)
cards.append(card2)
cards.append(card3)
```

Next, I test whether card1 is in the list of cards.

```
card1 in cards
Out[451]: True
```

That seems to be just fine. However,

```
card = Card(1,1)
card in cards
Out[453]: False
```

"card" looks the same as card1.

My question would be : Why is "card" NOT in the list cards?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the output of `card == card1`. They are not the same, even though you think they must be.

This is because in Python, the default check for equality is by object identity. `card` is a different (but similar) object from `card1`.

To let Python know how `Card` objects should be compared for equality, you have to define an `__eq__` method on the class.

```
class Card(object):
    ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.suit == other.suit and self.rank == other.rank
```

Comment: Really appreciate for your quick response. It works.